# How can I filter an array of objects using an object

Tags: object, filter, formula, workflow, unqork

I want to filter an object of object, looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK0vO.png), using a field form an other object, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WggwZ.png). I try to use the field `borough`. Which formula I should use in filter?

Answer (score 0):

If your are getting the borough input from any data collection pass that as input to filter and the input data containing borough by having Get operator to get borough from input data and pass as argument to filter. In filter condition, give as borough=_arg.